# Why are we in Public Beta now? And why is there no record of the Private Beta date from the API?

Tags: support, private-beta

We appear to be in public beta now. Why?

Also, courtesy of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390820/997587, the API gives this: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#page=1&pagesize=500&filter=!-CC*HqP9jrj7n6mK7I7P6sWh1.tA&run=true

```
{
  "open_beta_date": 1690297236,
  "site_url": "https://genai.stackexchange.com",
  "name": "GenAI"
},
```

Note the absence of the `closed_beta_date` property. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Regarding the API, unsurprisingly, because of how this site [came to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood), the tooling in Area 51 that normally creates that line in the database did not this time around, hence it was left empty. We have manually entered it and the API should catch up to it to include that information soonish.

---

We moved the site into public beta early due to the staff schedules and to make sure that we didn't screw it up, and that if we did we could fix it quickly.

The good news is that we didn't break anything except maybe something with the API. I don't know why that property is missing, let me raise that internally, and will update this answer later when I have it.